# MSVC 2015 choosing incorrect constructor overload for std::vector

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++

The following is part of my matrix class with a dynamic number of rows and columns, this class uses a `std::vector` in row-major order to store the matrix elements.

---

**`dynamic_matrix`**

```
template<typename _Ty,
    class _Alloc = std::allocator<_Ty>
> class dynamic_matrix {
public:
    typedef _Ty value_type;
    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    typedef _Alloc allocator_type;
    // various other typedefs, not relevant here...
    explicit dynamic_matrix(size_type _rows, size_type _cols, const _Alloc& alloc = _Alloc())
        : mtx(_rows*_cols, alloc), rows_(_rows), cols_(_cols) {}
    explicit dynamic_matrix(size_type _rows, size_type _cols, const value_type& _val,
        const _Alloc& alloc = _Alloc()) : mtx(_rows*_cols, _val, alloc), rows_(_rows), cols_(_cols) {}
    // other constructors and methods omitted...
private:
    std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc> mtx;
    size_type rows_;
    size_type cols_;
};
```

---

When I try to construct a `dynamic_matrix` using the first constructor in the snippet shown above with the following test,

```
int main(void) {
    dynamic_matrix<int> dm(10,10);
}
```

I get the following error from `MSVC 2015`:

```
std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc>::vector(std::initializer_list<int>,const std::allocator<_Ty>&)
: cannot convert argument 2 from 'const std::allocator<_Ty>' to 'const int&'
```

Whereas compiling this in `GCC 6.1.0` with the following command yields no warnings nor errors,

```
g++-6.1.0 --std=c++14 -Wall -pedantic -o maintest main.cpp dynamic_matrix.h
```

Using the second constructor in the `dynamic_matrix` code snippet above compiles fine for both GCC and MSVC.

The issue appears to be that MSVC is, for some reason, interpreting the constructor call `mtx(_rows*_cols, alloc)` as the 7th constructor from this [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) which would explain the `cannot convert from const std::allocator to const int&` error message. Whereas it appears GCC is using the 3rd constructor from the above reference as I intended.

Why is MSVC not choosing the correct constructor to call from `std::vector` whilst GCC is and what can I do to mitigate this?

Comment: What happens if you use `mtx{_rows*_cols, alloc}` instead?

Comment: Still gives the same error I'm afraid.

Comment: If the allocator is not all that important to you, it works if you leave it out.

Comment: Actually... If I look through the STL source in MSVC, I don't see a constructor that takes a count and an allocator. I could be mistaken about this, but I think the constructor you are trying to use simply does not exist in MSVC, whether by accident or not. There is, however, a constructor for count, fill-value, and allocator, so you could consider using that instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Status Update**

The bug has been fixed and was shipped in VS 2015 Update 3

---

Looking through the vector header in MSVS there is no constructor with the form

```
explicit vector( size_type count, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() )
```

But it does have

```
explicit vector(size_type _Count)
```

Which is a C++11 added constructor that was changed in C++14 to be former constructor.  It appears that MSVS has not caught up with that change yet.

What is really odd is that the specialization for `vector<bool>` does have the proper constructor in the header file and if you use

```
dynamic_matrix<bool> dm(10, 10);
```

it will compile.

I have filed a bug report with MS and you can see it [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2904820/std-vector-missing-c-14-constrcutor-change)

As a work around until this is fixed you can use the constructor with the form of

```
vector( size_type count, 
             const T& value,
             const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

and supply a value to construct the elements with.

Comment: I see, thanks for the bug report - I would've thought MS had applied this change by now.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury Same here.  It must have been overlooked/someone checked it off but forgot to do the work ;)

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury Added a possible work around.

Comment: Yeah that'll work, I can just use that constructor and default-initialise the values as the second argument.