# Cannot convert from 'const std::initializer_list<_Elem>' to 'const std::allocator<_Ty>' where both templates are int

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++11, visual-c++, stl

```
5> ...long path...\PredicateEquals.cpp(47): error C2664: 'std::vector<_Ty>::vector(const std::allocator<_Ty> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const std::initializer_list<_Elem>' to 'const std::allocator<_Ty> &'
5>          with
5>          [
5>              _Ty=int
5>          ]
5>          and
5>          [
5>              _Elem=int
5>          ]
5>          and
5>          [
5>              _Ty=int
5>          ]
5>          Reason: cannot convert from 'const std::initializer_list<_Elem>' to 'const std::allocator<_Ty>'
5>          with
5>          [
5>              _Elem=int
5>          ]
5>          and
5>          [
5>              _Ty=int
5>          ]
5>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

Note that both `_Elem=int` and `_Ty=int` so basically what fails is conversion from `const std::initializer_list<int>` to `const std::vector<int>`. I thought this was the very purpose of initializer lists - to convert them into arrays.

I based my code on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13979720/607407):

#### Header file

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <vector>
class Indexes {
public:
    Indexes(const std::initializer_list<int> uniqueIds);
protected:
    const std::vector<int> uniqueIds_;
};
```

#### Source file:

```
Indexes::Indexes( const std::initializer_list<int> uniqueIds )
    : 
    uniqueIds_(uniqueIds)
{}
```

The error comes from the source file, from the second constructor. How to properly use the initializer list for the constructor here? I'd prefer to keep `std::vector` a `const`ant. But removing the `const` did **not** remove the problem.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. The code compiles perfectly in GCC: http://ideone.com/HRC68a

Comment: MSVS2010 has horrible/basically no C++11 support.  I would strongly suggest getting a updated compiler.  It compiles in MSVS 2015 update 3.

Comment: @NathanOliver Please tell that to the powers that be, I can't buy new visual studio for a company. And yeah, I confirmed it's a Visual Studio issue: http://ideone.com/HRC68a

Comment: @TomášZato Perhaps you could write this up as an answer?

Comment: @JonathanMee I'm not convinced there is no workaround.

Comment: No sure why you got the down votes.  I did not vote.  Maybe the MCVE could be better but meh.

Comment: A [mcve] would help.

Comment: @juanchopanza I deleted some code to make it literally copy&paste job. Technically only thing that was necessary to delete was inheritance...

Comment: That is better. It is up to you to provide the [mcve], not for others to figure it out.

Comment: Deleting seemingly unrelated class members or methods sometimes leads to the problem dissapearing, especially with the visual studio compiler I'm using. Admitedly, in this case I tried it and it didn't help.

Comment: Yes, but obviously if they lead to the problem disappearing then don't delete them. If they don't make any difference to the problem then you should already have deleted them before posting the question, so that we aren't wasting time looking at unrelated bits of irrelevant code (_especially_ if those bits of irrelevant code prevent it being compiled). The meaning of MCVE is clear, and irrelevant code that can't be compiled has no place in the MCVE.

Comment: @TomášZato I do not have MSVS 2010 so I cannot check but if you can explore the `std::vector` header then see if it has a constructor that takes a `std::initializer_list`.  I have a open bug report on the regarding C++14([answer that started it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38251914/msvc-2015-choosing-incorrect-constructor-overload-for-stdvector/38253128#38253128)).

Comment: @juanchopanza I see what you did there :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <vector>
class Indexes {
public:
#ifdef PRE_CXX11_COMPILER
    template<typename... T>
      Indexes(T... t) : uniqueIds_{t...} { }
#else
    Indexes(const std::initializer_list<int> uniqueIds) : uniqueIds_{uniqueIds} { }
#endif
protected:
    const std::vector<int> uniqueIds_;
};
```

But I have no idea if that will work with MSVC 2010 either.

If you can't change your toolchain then you need to avoid C++ 2011 features that a 2010 compiler doesn't support.

Comment: So you want to use variadic templates for the pre-c++11 compiler? That's not going to work...

Comment: @rubenvb it might, C++11 support is pretty random in MSVC compiler. For example, lambdas sometimes work, sometimes they don't.

Comment: @TomášZato it's not random, it's documented: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#corelanguagetable.

Comment: @rubenvb, as I said, you can _try_ it, but I don't know if it will work with MSVC 2010. It worked with GCC more than a decade ago :-P

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know GCC had variadic templates before `initializer_list` :o. But this won't do for MSVC. Not at all  :/.

Answer (score 0):

So far, only thing I have is a **workaround** that uses plain old C varargs feature. This is nothing like initializer lists and requires you pass `-1` as last parameter. I do **not** recommend using this if you can upgrade your compiler. **Failing to pass correct parameters results in segmentation fault**. But in my case rot of repetitive unreadable code would ensue if instead filled vectors manually using `std::vector::push_back`.

#### Header file

```
#include <vector>
#ifdef CPP_11_COMPILER
  #include <initializer_list>
#else
  #include <stdarg.h>
#endif

class Indexes {
public:
    // Constructor with standard vector
    Indexes(const std::vector<int>& uniqueIds);
    #ifdef CPP_11_COMPILER
    Indexes(const std::initializer_list<int> uniqueIds);
    #else
    // Static method to construct the std::vector and then the class' instance
    // ☠☠☠ WARNING: variadric arguments must be of type short! Last argument MUST BE -1!!!
    static Indexes with_initializer_list(const int unused, ...);
    #endif
protected:
    const std::vector<int> uniqueIds_;
};
```

#### Source file

```
Indexes::Indexes( const std::vector<int>& uniqueIds )
: uniqueIds_(uniqueIds)
{}

#ifdef CPP_11_COMPILER
Indexes::Indexes( const std::initializer_list<int> uniqueIds )
    : uniqueIds_(uniqueIds)

{}
#else
Indexes Indexes::with_initializer_list( const int unused, ... )
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, unused);
    std::vector<int> items;

    int entry = 0;
    while((entry = va_arg(ap, short))>=0) {
        items.push_back(entry);
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return Indexes(items);
}
#endif
```

#### Usage

The solution isn't exactly reliable, but is best fit before an upgrade of compiler happens:

```
Indexes indexes = Indexes::with_initializer_list(0, (short)1,(short)2,(short)3,(short)-1);
// indexes' vector now contains [1, 2, 3]
```